# how to get IPBX_NonVisualObject from a pbobject handle?

Tags: powerbuilder

I have two non visual objects in a PBNI extension and I want to use one of these objects as a parameter for a method in the other object.

```
obj_a = create pbni_obj_a
obj_b = create pbni_obj_b
obj_b.process(obj_a, "send")
```

where pbni_obj_a and pbni_obj_b are PBNI objects from the same PBX extension.

I want to get the C++ object (obj_a PBNI implementation) inside the obj_b.process method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using IPB_Session::IsNativeObject(pbobject obj) and IPB_Session::GetNativeInterface(pbobject obj) ?